# PhpStorm warns about incorrect namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, phpstorm

I'm used to working with Laravel but getting a bit confused with namespace in a new project based off Laravel 10 and using PhpStorm as my IDE.

In the `composer.json` file the default autoload has been set to:

```json
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

In my user model my IDE is throwing an error that the namespace is incorrect. The namespace is the default one for the user model:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

The IDE suggests *"Namespace name doesn't match the PSR-0/PSR-4 project structure"* and suggests moving the class to `app/App/Models` from it's current location of `app/Models`.

This is where I'm confused. I assumed the PSR autoload effectively set the root of `App` to the root folder of `app` - is this correct?

I've done a `composer dump autoload` but the IDE errors still appear - the app does appear to be working so is this a PhpStorm set up issue?

Looking back at an older Laravel project the PSR-4 entry for app did not feature.

How can I resolve and ensure namespace is correct? (or change settings in IDE)

Comment: Do you have a `classmap` section in your autoload? Or is that your full autoload section?

Comment: I had a similar problem and after running "Invalidate caches…" (to find under the file menu of PHPStorm) the problem was solved.

Comment: 1) Use `File | Invalidate Caches...`, restart the IDE and let it reindex your project -- any better? 2) Show what you have in `Settings/Preferences | Directories` -- interested in your Source Roots. With default settings the IDE will sync the namespace mappings with composer.json (the later one is the source).

Comment: composer.json and namespaces are fine. Must be a PHPStrom issue. Someone should post "Invalidate Caches" as an answer.